# How to reference a patent with BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex

What is the best entity to use with BibTeX in order to reference a patent or patent application?

Comment: Which BibTeX style do you use?

Comment: I'm using `abbrv`

Comment: This looks good (but in German): ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505/normpatsoft.pdf They use MISC. The field `type` can be used to name it as `patent`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'traditional' BibTeX styles do not include an entry type for patents. As such, any entry of the form

```
@patent{...
```

will be treated as a `misc` entry.  The formatting that results, may well not be what you want, so I would recommend doing things 'by hand' using the `misc` type and `howpublished` field.

[Some styles *do* recognise patents. The exact details of the fields supported vary a bit, so it's best to consult the appropriate documentation.)

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend creating your own `misc` entry on BibTeX and populating the `howpublished` field with your patent's pre-print URL if possible. The website [bibtex.online](https://bibtex.online) can convert online your BibTeX entry/ies to formatted text in other formats: APA, MLA, Chicago, etc.

For instance:
[image: bibtex.online misc entry]