# Extended support for standard/norm/spec entries in bibtex/biblatex?

Tags: bibliographies, custom-bib, bibentry

A couple of times when using `bibtex`, I would have liked to have a direct support for citing and formatting entries of **standards** (also specifications, directives, norms, RFCs, and the like) in my bibliographies.

1. With `bibtex`, the typical way is to use the `@misc` entry format (see, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79392/how-to-reference-a-patent-with-bibtex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/how-to-cite-omg-specifications)).  That has been my approach for years. Alternatively, one can also use `@manual` and `@techreport`.
2. `biblatex` supports *patents* and, [though, "unsupported"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65637/how-to-cite-a-standard-iso-etc-in-biblatex), also *standards*. (It is [unclear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261011/difference-between-organization-and-institution-when-citing-a-standard) to me what "unsupported" means.) Anyway, a switch to `biblatex` came in handy, usually.
3. One can craft their own custom entry types with either of the bibliography packages, e.g. using `custom-bib`. (Though, I am not courageous enough to work that through.)

Regarding 3., would [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65753/164050) be a "standard" way to do it? Are there attempts to extend the predefined set of entry types of `bibtex` and to include standards in the supported set of entry types in `biblatex`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

PLK's answer to [How to cite a standard (ISO, etc.) in BibLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65637/35864) that you cite in your question is actually not an example of using [`custom-bib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib). `custom-bib` is a tool to produce customised `.bst` files for use with BibTeX. PLK's answer was specifically about implementing a more useful `@standard` driver for `biblatex`.

## BibTeX styles

Not a lot of `.bst` styles seem to support types like `@patent` or `@standard`. On my machine I could find the `IEEEtran` styles (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) with support for `@patent`, `@standard` and `achemso` (https://ctan.org/pkg/achemso) with support for `@patent`.

## `custom-bib`

`custom-bib` is an awesome way to create a customised bibliography style for BibTeX by answering a series of questions about your desired result (seriously, I hadn't used the tool in a few years and I was really impressed by the customisations it offers and the result). But fundamentally, `custom-bib` has to stick to a certain framework of entry types and modifications. As far as I can see there is no way to make `custom-bib` create new entry types like `@standard` or `@patent`. So you would have to add these types and their definition by hand afterwards. This is certainly not impossible, but it is going to be quite some work and BibTeX's reverse Polish notation may need a few moments of getting used to.

## `biblatex`

With `biblatex` an approach similar to [How to cite a standard (ISO, etc.) in BibLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65637/35864) would be the way to go if the default behaviour is not satisfying (it probably is not).

The "unsupported" status of `@standard` and other `biblatex` type was an unfortunate choice of word (for a section heading) that has given rise to confusion. See for example [Biblatex: unsupported entry types - why are they defined at all?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434281/35864). In the next version of `biblatex` `@standard` and the other types listed in that section will be "non-standard" types. This might still confuse people, but it describes the situation more accurately. These types are officially recognised and accepted, valid entry types, but the `biblatex` standard styles do not have a driver definition set up for these types and will essentially use a fall-back definition (the `@misc` driver). Some contributed styles, however, may have more specific definitions in place and you can certainly roll your own definition.

## Efforts to bring `@patent` and `@standard` to more styles

### BibTeX

I am not aware of a concentrated effort to bring `@patent` and `@standard` to existing BibTeX styles. Many styles have remained untouched for years and I doubt that a lot of them will be updated (the vast number of styles available on CTAN have been contributed by many different people, updating their work would require contacting them). I guess people manage to get by with `@misc` and a bit of hackery so that there is no pressing need to start such a huge effort. Compare this to the situation with URLs in `.bst` files. Some of the early `.bst` files were written back when URLs were not really a thing and while many modern styles already support URLs, some old (especially the base styles) do not. There are projects like [`urlbst`](https://ctan.org/pkg/urlbst) and many newer styles support URLs, but the base styles still don't. And I guess the number of people who are interested in URL support is at least one magnitude larger than those who are passionate about `@standard` and `@patent` entries.

### `biblatex`

As for `biblatex` there is https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/388. Aside from the policy question there is always the question of what exactly should be implemented. Different standard bodies may have different ways of referring to their standards and so it is not clear to me whether one could implement a useful generic `@standard` that works with all `biblatex` standard styles. (How should a `@standard` citation to ISO8601 look in `style=authoryear`? It seems that this would require changes to the citation macros that would make them quite unsightly.)

Comment: Thank you, @moewe, for this comprehensive guidance. Sorry for my misunderstanding of `custom-bib`. **I think, `IEEEtran` and the standard-to-misc mapping of `biblatex` are a good start.** And, the URL issue you mentioned is kind of a heavily desired feature of bibtex, although, there are quite comfortable fixes for that.

Comment: @Mario Re the URL feature see also https://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A1=ind1805&L=LATEX-L#1. I mentioned it only to provide perspective on how likely it is that the base styles would be changed.

Comment: The template https://www.beuth.de/de/hilfe/hilfezitierenvonnormen indeed covers a variety. The pattern to be followed would be comparable to book/inbook, collection/incollection: i.e. whole standard/part of standard. Standards often come in parts (= chapters), inkl. appendices/informative addendums. So people would refer to the standard (as a collection of parts) _OR_ to a specific part, typically including the version (cf. techreports but with YYYY-MM). Author would be omitted, instead using  abbreviations of the Orgs/Insts/Working Groups, e.g. ISO EN, BS, DIN, IEC, CENELEC, whatever.

Comment: Regarding the URL, I get the point. Those seem to be long discussed issues which might require quite some changes in the original design with undesired impact, right?

Comment: @Mario To be honest I don't know why the BIbTeX standard styles were not changed to include URLs at some point. The technical side is actually fairly easy. After a while it would have been a backwards compatibility problem, but especially in the early days it could have been marketed as a new feature and the backwards compatibility reservations would not have been grave. My hypothesis is that the BibTeX developer was busy with other things and did not give this high priority since people can write their own styles.

Comment: @Mario While the citation recommendation from Beuth works for ISO (and I assume DIN and most other members of ISO) it does not work for all standard bodies. Cf. http://www.aes.org/publications/standards/search.cfm?docID=18, https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/, https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BT.601/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GPP, http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-007r2/12-007r2.html. Each body has its own set of idiosyncrasies that it would like to see honoured, so it is really tricky to build something that is universal and yet simple...

Comment: ... Simplicity is something that the standard styles should try to maintain (to a certain degree), they should be easily extensible and *understandable*. I really don't want the `biblatex` standard styles to become as complicated as `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-chicago` just to typeset ISO norms properly. While a bibliography driver could be built to satisfy the ISO quite easily it would take quite a bit of effort to integrate the citation for anything other than the `numeric` styles in a clean *and backwards compatible* way.

Comment: Dear @Moewe, thanks for the clarification. So, as a mere user, I realise that I do not have an idea about the complexity of the hierarchy of bibliography drivers. I can imagine that one can come up with a pragmatically unified driver covering most idiosyncracies of the standards you mentioned. Handling norm-types x citation-styles + backwards-compatibility + core-stability seems tough. I will try to stick with what is there, biblatex is cool anyway.